# How do I qqplot values from different treatment groups?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stcm8.jpg)
I apologize for the simple question, I just started using R for my school assignment.
I am trying to make 3 qq plots for each treatment group (i.e. control, QA-PBS,QA-iPSC), but I dont know how to describe it to find the function online. Here is the image of the data.
Thank you very much.

Experimental

```
Data<-structure(list(group = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Control","Control","Control","QA-PBS","QA-PBS","QA-PBS","QA-PBS","QA-PBS","QA-PBS","QA-PBS","QA-iPSC","QA-iPSC","QA-iPSC","QA-iPSC","QA-iPSC","QA-iPSC","QA-iPSC"),crossovers = c(9L,6L,10L,10L,8L,9L,0L,1L,0L,4L,4L,2L,4L,6L,8L,5L,8L,5L,7L,4L)),.Names=c("group","crossovers"),row.names=c(NA,-20L),class=c("tbl_df","tbl","data.frame"),spec= structure(list(cols=structure(list(group=structure(list(),class=c("collector_character","collector")),crossovers=structure(list(),class=c("collector_integer","collector"))),.Names=c("group","crossover)),default=structure(list(),class =c("collector_guess","collector"))),.Names=c("cols","default"),class="col_spec"))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: I am trying to check the normality for ANOVA conditions, so i need 3 QQ plots for y value ("crossovers") for each group(control,QA-iPSC,QA-PBS)
p.s the "enter image description here" is the image link

Comment: We do not need you to repeat your question again. Please provide a reproducible example of your data, such as using `dput`.

Comment: First, use `qqnorm` because `qqplot` is used to compare one dataset's distribution to another's. Use `subset` to separate the groups as follows: `Gp1 <- subset(data, control=='Control')`; and then `qqnorm(Gp1$crossovers)`, etc. There are other more advanced, even elegant, ways to do this, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

If you will accept a `ggplot2` solution, then you can do the following:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample = crossovers)) +
  geom_qq() + geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]